# Applescript access to last.fm app via application icon in menu bar

Tags: applescript, menubar

I want to create an Applescript to drive the last.fm player app. I'm trying to do this via last.fm application icon in the menu bar rather than using the main application menus, as this approach (I think) won't cause last.fm to switch to the foreground. The overall plan is to bind my script to a quicksilver trigger so I can stop|start|skip|love|ban|tag tracks from the keyboard.

My problem is I can't find what UI element to bind the applescript to. I've used [UI Browser](http://prefabsoftware.com/uibrowser/) to scan through the UI object model but it draws a blank with the last.fm icon in the menu bar. Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Items in the menu bar are NSStatusItem and the part of the menu bar in which they live is an NSStatusBar.  I suspect from past experience, though I am not sure, that if your applescript would have caused the main application to switch to the foreground, it will cause the menu bar item to switch to the foreground to the extent that it can, meaning that the application in the foreground will probably lose focus.